# Parsing 400 Response in Angular 10 to get ModelState Issues

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I have a very simple controller action that takes in a viewmodel. I simply want to check the model in code and if it's not valid, dump the modelstate back as a BadRequest.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("SaveBraceStep1")]
[SwaggerOperation(OperationId = "SaveBraceStep1")]
[ProducesResponseType(200, Type = typeof(VM.ProjectBraceDataModelStep1))]
public async Task<IActionResult> SaveBraceStep1(VM.ProjectBraceDataModelStep1 model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return new BadRequestObjectResult(ModelState.Errors());
  }
  var project = await bracingDataService.SaveBraceStep1(model);
  return Ok(project);
}
```

When the result comes back to Chrome, it's as expected.

[image: Here is the 400 response I receive from the the]

I have an http interceptor as follows:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(catchError(err => {
                // how can I read the results of the ModelState here
                console.log(err);
                return throwError('An error has been thrown');
            }));
    }
}
```

Here is what is dumped to the console

[image: Console Log of Error]

I've scoured thru tons of google searches and user blobs, but I can't seem to find an accepted concise way to do this.

I'm really blown away since I would expect this to be pretty much standardized by now.

Any Thoughts? Thank you in advance. Happy Coding!

~Mike

Comment: Dis you try to console the err..?

Comment: I updated the question with the results of a console.log of the err. Thanks.

Comment: I'm looking into the FileReader object to read the error pieces of the result.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured this out with the help from https://www.strathweb.com/2018/07/centralized-exception-handling-and-request-validation-in-asp-net-core/

You basically have to register a new Action Type, then insert it into the pipeline.

```
public Task ExecuteResultAsync(ActionContext context)
    {
      var modelStateEntries = context.ModelState.Where(e => e.Value.Errors.Count > 0).ToArray();
      var errors = new List<ValidationError>();

      var details = "See ValidationErrors for details";

      if (modelStateEntries.Any())
      {
        if (modelStateEntries.Length == 1 && modelStateEntries[0].Value.Errors.Count == 1 && modelStateEntries[0].Key == string.Empty)
        {
          details = modelStateEntries[0].Value.Errors[0].ErrorMessage;
        }
        else
        {
          foreach (var modelStateEntry in modelStateEntries)
          {
            foreach (var modelStateError in modelStateEntry.Value.Errors)
            {
              var error = new ValidationError
              {
                Name = modelStateEntry.Key,
                Description = modelStateError.ErrorMessage
              };

              errors.Add(error);
            }
          }
        }
      }

      var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails
      {
        Status = 400,
        Title = "Request Validation Error",
        Instance = $"urn:myorganization:badrequest:{Guid.NewGuid()}",
        Detail = details,
        ValidationErrors = errors
      };
      context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 400;
      var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(problemDetails);
      context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(json);
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
  }
  public class ValidationProblemDetails : ProblemDetails
  {
    public ICollection<ValidationError> ValidationErrors { get; set; }
  }
  public class ValidationError
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
  }
```

Then in startup.cs register it.

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
      {
        options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = ctx => new ValidationProblemDetailsResult();
      });
```

Then wired up in the interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private uiService: Services.UIService, private injector: Injector) {
    }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(request)
            .pipe(catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.addEventListener('loadend', (e) => {
                    const result = this.buildResponse(JSON.parse(e.srcElement['result']));
                    this.uiService.HttpError(result);
                });
                reader.readAsText(err.error);
                return throwError(err);
            }));
    }

    buildResponse(e: any): ApplicationHttpErrorResponse {
        const model: ApplicationHttpErrorResponse = { ValidationErrors: [] };
        if (e.ValidationErrors && e.ValidationErrors.length > 0) {
            for (let i = 0; i < e.ValidationErrors.length; i++) {
                const validator: ApplicationHttpError = {
                    Name: e.ValidationErrors[i].Name,
                    Description: e.ValidationErrors[i].Description
                };
                model.ValidationErrors.push(validator);
            }
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

It can then be used in the UI service to display issues to the end user.